# "Disciplined" achievement badge awarded for migrated answer

Tags: bug

This just happened:

INBOX

(Programmers SE item)
 answer migrated 2 hours ago
Your answer to "Testing a method that reads from standard input and outputs to standard output" was migrated to Stack Overflow.

ACHIEVEMENTS

(Programmers SE item)
You've earned the "Disciplined" badge (Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher) for "Testing a method that reads from standard input and outputs to standard output".

---

Needless to say, I did not delete [my own post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277302/testing-a-method-that-reads-from-standard-input-and-outputs-to-standard-output/277303#277303?noredirect=1).  Apparently, the migration was counted as deletion, and for this reason the "Disciplined" badge was awarded.

On second thought, thisissuchanunimportantbug.

<sub>noneedtodoanythingaboutitreally.</sub>

Comment: You did delete (and then undelete) the answer at one point and it looks like that's what we're picking up on. I'll have to dig more tomorrow/soon when I have the code in front of me to be sure, but my gut feel is that this is a narrow enough case that it's probably not worth fixing. But if it's easy, we'll fix it up. Either way, though, enjoy the badge. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I did briefly delete and undelete the answer, but that happened when it still had zero upvotes.